# Override TSQL query to another

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, ado.net

In our company we have a windows application that we can't develop it any more. This application use one of our live databases.
there is a query like this, that we spend a lot of resource to response this expensive query:

```
SELECT * FROM City
```

My question is, is there any way that when this query execute to database, override it with some thing else. For example change it to:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Name, Code FROM City
```

Comment: You can rename the city table to something else and create a view containing just those 2 columns. You cannot have top 10 inside a view though.

Comment: *"You cannot have top 10 inside a view though."* @SalmanA yes you can, the query just needs an `ORDER BY` too. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=99374abe626938caf1d43bb0af92deb2)

Comment: Because other applications use this table and use different columns of this we can't change it. but I want to override just this query patter to another.

Comment: Afaik there is no way to accomplish this directly insde SQL Server; although you can track and gather info on submitted queries using DMV or events, there are no "hooks" to intercept a request. I wonder if there might be a way to change the table to a view and have the view use a function and the function check meta data such as the application name of the `Session_Id`...?

Comment: Why can't you fix the application?

Comment: There's nothing built into SQL Server that will let you achieve this. There are commercial products, like ScaleArc, that are basically big old TDS (Tabular Data Stream) protocol proxy servers that allow you to do funky things like load balance SELECT queries across multiple read-only replicas, with DML statements only going to the master, but I don't think they let you rewrite the queries. There's nothing stopping you downloading the MS-TDS specification, though, and writing your own purpose-built proxy server to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Spinning on the idea in @Stu's comment...

Table is renamed into City_Table (sqlfiddle does not work at the time of writing, sorry):

```
CREATE TABLE City_Table (Code INT, Name VARCHAR(20))
GO
INSERT INTO City_Table (Code, Name)
SELECT 1, 'City1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'City2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'City3'
```

Then a view could try to check the last command issued from current spid:

```
CREATE VIEW City 
AS
SELECT Code, [Name] FROM 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Code) rownum, Code, [Name] 
    FROM City_Table
) sub
WHERE 
LTRIM(RTRIM(
    (SELECT TEXT as query
    FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(most_recent_sql_handle)
    WHERE session_id = (SELECT @@SPID)
    )
))  
!= 'SELECT * FROM City'
OR sub.rownum <= 2
```

Then a query `SELECT * FROM City` will return

| Code | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | City1 |
| 2 | City2 |

whereas a query like `SELECT * FROM City ORDER BY 1` will return

| Code | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | City1 |
| 2 | City2 |
| 3 | City3 |

But to be honest: I'm not sure at all if this is a **reliable** way to find the last issued command in a specific application's scenario. And for sure querying sys views by an app user **might raise security issues**. Just been curious to test it out.